# Does my MacBook Pro have an expiry date?

Tags: hardware

While dismantling my 2011 MacBook Pro, I found that the bottom case place has an etching:

[image]

What does it all mean? In particular, one part of it appears to be a date in the future. Is it, and if so what happens on that day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not likely an expiry date, as much as an end of cycle for manufacturing. The date April 24, 2012 bears no significance to the Macbook Pro. The 2011 Macbook Pro was the second last edition of the Macbook Pro line and was released in October 2011, as June 2012 saw the release of the Macbook Pro Retina line and the final Macbook Pro. If you were to open up a 2012 MBP, you would likely see a different date listed on the 604-2751-C part. Given the lead times to manufacture, it would make sense that there was no further production of the Macbook Pro bottom plate past that date.